# How do I create a linked keyword index?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, lookup-column

We have a 2000-document library that we use as a knowledge base. We're trying to create a hyperlinked index of keywords. In this simplified example, consider the following metadata for a document library:

```
Document_Name_Column | Keyword_Column
---------------------+--------------- 
Document_1.html      | foo1, foo2
Document_2.html      | foo3
Document_3.html      | foo4, foo5
Docuemnt_4.html      | foo6, foo7
```

I want to create a webpart that displays

```
foo1   
foo2    
foo3     
foo4    
foo5    
foo6  
foo7
foo8
```

with each displayed keyword linking back to document top which it refers.

In essence, I want to use the data in my document library to create and display

```
<a href="../DocLib/Document_1.html">foo1</a><br>
<a href="../DocLib/Document_1.html">foo2</a><br>
<a href="../DocLib/Document_2.html">foo3</a><br>
<a href="../DocLib/Document_3.html">foo4</a><br>
<a href="../DocLib/Document_3.html">foo5</a><br>
<a href="../DocLib/Document_4.html">foo6</a><br>
<a href="../DocLib/Document_4.html">foo7</a><br>
```

What's a good way to proceed? I suspect some sort of linked or lookup column may be appropriate, but I'm not terribly familiar with those...